What's the URL of Events Service and how to register a webhook?
The Events Service URL is not indicated in the repository's README: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-events-service?tab=readme-ov-file#how-to-integrate-with-the-service
So I cannot register a webhook to subscribe to Safe events. Also, how is it possible to register webhooks? It does not seem to be indicated either.
When is it planned to support Safe-specific webhooks? It is too costly right now to host a server that gets pinged for all Safe transactions...
Thanks

We are evaluating how to allow teams to integrate with us. In the meantime running your own server is the only way to get events.
